# ssh key error - Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

Amazon Ec2 :: Redhat 6. 64 Bit
I'm trying to follow the socks5 guidelines (http://www.catonmat.net/blog/linux-socks5-proxy/ ) to open a socks on one of our servers but unfortunately I got suck at step 1 .

```
ssh -N -D 0.0.0.0:1080 localhost
```

I get error

```
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

How do I fix it ?

More debug info

ssh -v -f -N -D 0.0.0.0:1080 localhost

```
OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.0-fips 29 Mar 2010
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to localhost [127.0.0.1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host 'localhost' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
debug1: No valid Key exchange context
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_0' not found

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_0' not found

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information

debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/identity
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

Comment: Add the `-d` flag to get more information.

Comment: Put the `-d` to the front of the options.

Comment: check for firewall/permissions. I think your firewall preventing it.

Comment: alexus selinux is disabled. Btw the server provider is Amazon AWS

Comment: What ott probably means to say is `-v` for VERBOSE output.  Edit your question and add the verbose output.

Comment: So are you able to connect to that host with SSH, if you aren't trying to use the `-D` option to connect?

Comment: @Zoredache I actually use the same 0.0.0.0 ... is not a different IP. It's meant to open a socks5 proxy on linux. Did I misunderstood the guidelines ( http://www.catonmat.net/blog/linux-socks5-proxy/  ) ?

Comment: What happens if you do just `ssh localhost`?

Comment: I get the same error ssh localhost
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).

Answer (score 2):

check for permissions and ownership on the server:

- home
- .ssh dir
- authorized_keys

Answer (score 1):

SSH at EC2 doesn't allow connecting without ssh key (password login are denied, even to localhost).e.g. 
ssh -i mykey.pem -N -D 0.0.0.0:1080 localhost

Answer (score 1):

ssh looks for the private key file named **id_rsa** and it doesn't find it. It's possible that you used ssh-keygen to generate the key pair and gave the files another name. If this is the case, try to rename those files to id_rsa and id_rsa.pub, or try

```
ssh -v -i private_key_file_name -f -N -D 0.0.0.0:1080 localhost
```